# Compile-time disabled code with C++20 modules?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, c++20, c++-modules

I was working on a small example program, as a prototype proof-of-concept:

```cpp
// disable_lib.cpp
export module disable_lib;
import <iostream>;

extern bool bDoStuff;

export void do_stuff()
{
    if (bDoStuff) { std::cout << "stuff" << std::endl; }
}
```

This module compiles with with this command:

```bash
g++-13 -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -ggdb -c disable_lib.cpp -o disable_lib.o
```

Naturally, I tried to declare `bDoStuff` as extern, because I want its definition specified in another translation unit, which could look like this:

```cpp
import disable_lib;
bDoStuff = false;

int main()
{
    do_stuff(); // <-- here, we should not print "stuff" !
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the main file, I get relocation errors:

```bash
/usr/bin/ld: disable_lib.o: warning: relocation against `_ZW11disable_lib8bDoStuff' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: disable_lib.o: in function `do_stuff@disable_lib()':
/home/gg/my-repos/modules-presentation/code/disable_lib.cpp:13: undefined reference to `bDoStuff@disable_lib'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What I *would like to achieve* is a way of compiling a main file, which strictly fullfills to criteria:

1. The assignment of `bDoStuff` gets evaluated **at compile-time**;
2. the `std::cout` call does not get executed; and
3. the function call to `do_stuff()` gets stripped from the binary

To satisfy 3), I might need to flag with `-lto`, but obviously I didn't get that far yet.

#### Question

Is there a way to achieve 1), 2) and 3) while using C++ modules?

Comment: Would `extern bool ::bDoStuff;` help?

Comment: @TedLyngmo My compiler complains: "_‘bDoStuff’ should have been declared inside ‘::’_" when I try to do this inside the module unit. Inside the main file it doesn't work at all. So no, I'm not sure if it helps. :/ thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to `extern` declare it _outside_ your module scope. Do `extern bool bDoStuff;` before `export module disable_lib;` and then access it with `::` inside your module: `if (::bDoStuff)` etc. I can't test if it works myself, but I think it may work. Otherwise, the `extern` declaration makes `bDoStuff` a variable in the module.

Comment: I don't think you can make it `constexpr` though. That would require the definition to be visible when compiling the module.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Unfortunately, anything below `export module <...>` is considered part of the named module until EOF. Anything above must be part of global module fragment, introduced with `module;`. But now an inclusion error: "_error: global module fragment contents must be from preprocessor inclusion_".

Comment: @TedLyngmo And yes, `constexpr` must be "evaluatable" at module compile-time.. this was my first try and fail as well.
I think I want/_need_ something that is **part of** the module, ie. parsed and serialized as part of the module AST, but also compile-time enforced by the client translation unit.
At this point I'm fumbling blindly...
(and I would like to avoid macros altogether)

Comment: Where is this `bDostuff` supposed to be defined?

Comment: @Red.Wave I was thinking inside the translation unit which imports the module. But from Nicol Bolas' answer it sounds like that is not doable.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is not a thing that could happen *without* modules (unless you use macros), let alone with them.

If a variable is declared `constexpr`, it has to have an initializer. This means it must be a definition and therefore cannot be redefined in this TU. A `const` qualified variable declaration also must have an initializer.

Because of this, there's no way for code outside of this TU, or later in some inclusion graph, to change what value the variable has.

Compilers *can* do link-time optimizations for stuff that isn't `const` or `constexpr`. But that's the best you could hope for.

Again, this is true whether you're using modules or not.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. I did watch a talk with Bjarne Stroustrup where he mentioned that the committee is interested in getting rid of the precompiler _eventually_. So I thought that there might be a way.
My own solution around this problem (answer provided) uses macros, which I'm not super big fan of, but maybe that's still the best answer?

Comment: @alexpanter: "*I did watch a talk with Bjarne Stroustrup where he mentioned that the committee is interested in getting rid of the precompiler eventually.*" Do not take the words of Stroustrup as indicative of what is going to happen with C++. However much he might want to, it is functionally impractical to remove it. Lessen its utility relative to alternatives? Certainly. Get rid of it? Nope.

Answer (score 0):

#### Disclaimer

I'm not *completely* satisfied with this solution, but for the sake of spreading knowledge I include this here as a possible solution.

If there is an answer that **does not** involve the use of macros, I would still be interested in hearing about it.

#### Macros (again)

This is a version of the library that at least works:

```cpp
// disable_lib.cpp
export module disable_lib;
import <iostream>;

#if defined(DLIB_DISABLE_LOG)
constexpr bool bDoStuff = false;
#else
constexpr bool bDoStuff = true;
#endif

export void do_stuff()
{
    if constexpr (bDoStuff)
    {
        std::cout << "stuff" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And the client translation unit:

```cpp
import disable_lib;

int main()
{
    do_stuff();

    return 0;
}
```

And to compile, here with Ubuntu 23.04, g++-13, and language standard 23:

```bash
g++-13 -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -ggdb -c disable_lib.cpp -o disable_lib.o
g++-13 -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -ggdb disable_test.cpp disable_lib.o -o disable_test
./disable_test
stuff

g++-13 -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -ggdb -DDLIB_DISABLE_LOG -c disable_lib.cpp -o disable_lib_release.o
g++-13 -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -ggdb disable_test.cpp disable_lib_release.o -o disable_test_release
./disable_test_release
```

When compiled with the `DLIB_DISABLE_LOG` macro, no output is generated. Also, since the code uses `if constexpr` I assume that there is a compile-time check which generates an empty function.